Can't connect Mac to Apple Vision Pro for Xcode Development
I am trying to download Xcode apps from my M1 Mac to my Apple Vision Pro for testing. I have tried following the instructions by going into Settings->General->Remote Devices on my Apple Vision Pro, but there my Mac does not show up as a possible connection. Per this page, I have made sure that both devices are connected to the same WiFi network, updated my Mac to Sonoma, and updated my AVP to the latest OS, and everything else that it asks for.
I am able to mirror my display from my Mac but downloading apps from Xcode does not work. I have also looked to enable Developer Mode by going to Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Enable Developer Mode, but there is no option for enabling developer mode here.
I have tried looking at similar issues on Stack Overflow, but following their solutions have not helped for mine. I am already using an M1 Mac, have updated both my Mac and Vision Pro to latest software, have enabled bluetooth, and have signed into the same Apple ID on both.
Per this forum, I initially thought the issue was a Bonjour Protocol compatibility issue since both devices are on university wifi (WPA2-Enterprise), but I also tried connecting both over a hotspot and normal WPA2 wifi which also did not work.

Try these search results.

Unfortunately I have already tried all of the solutions from those search results. My post above details which ones I've tried and that they don't work.

In case anyone comes here searching for answers try connecting to a different wifi network. I've had the same issue on a 2.4GHz but it worked well on a 5GHz one.
